# Nginx except root, all others are redirected to 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

My goal is to put two or more(in future) Laravel applications under single domain and do the aliasing eg: http://domain-name/Lara-1  and http://domain-name/Lara-2. 
I had trouble in aliasing and finally was able to do it by using locations but now, Except the root Laravel index.php of both apps, all other uris result in **404 error**. 
Followed is my sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    server_name Domain-IP;

     location ^~ /Lara-1/ {
        alias /var/www/Lara-1/public/;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
         }

     location ^~ /Lara-2/ {
     alias /var/www/Lara-2/public/;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

  location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
 }
```

In-case of single app instead of two i.e. only Lara-1, when I put the root as 
/var/www/Lara-1/public/; everything works fine. Above situation happens only in case of app alias. May be, i may have configured it wrong.

Followed is my fastcgi_params file:

```html
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

I am a newbie to Nginx and Laravel. Appreciate your help!

Comment: What is in the `fastcgi_params` include file?

Comment: @RichardSmith: Modified above with fastcgi_params content. Thnx.

Comment: @usernamehidden Can you share your solution?

Comment: @BhargavMehta: I updated with an answer, please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this apps working after trials and errors. Following is how my Nginx default file looks like with 2 Laravel apps placed under webroot dir. 
Happened to use Nginx Url Rewrites.    Hope it helps!

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 172.3.21.1;
    root /var/www/webroot/;

location /projectdev {
        rewrite ^/projectdev/(.*)$ /projectdev/public/index.php?$1 last;
    }       

location /projectqa {
        rewrite ^/projectqa/(.*)$ /projectqa/public/index.php?$1 last;
    }
    error_page 401 403 404 /404.html;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

     location ~ \.php$ {    
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;   
    }

    location ~* .(woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
               expires 365d;
    }
    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    # Block web attacks
    location ~* (roundcube|webdav|smtp|http\:|soap|w00tw00t)
    {
    return 444;
    }

    # Protect .ini files
    location ~ /\.ini
    {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
    }
     location ~ /\.xml {
            deny all;
    }
}
```